# static construction method vs constructor

Tags: c#, .net, class-design

In the .NET framework I often see the idiom where a constructor is replaced by a static function to construct a new object from.

For instance with BigInteger there's no constructor taking a string so this is not possible:

```
BigInteger i = new BigInteger("1000000103453543897");
```

But there is a static Parse function.

```
BigInteger i = BigInteger.Parse("1000000103453543897");
```

Why is a class design like this often chosen?

The only thing I can think of is there's one object less to be created and later thrown away. Is it true that that is the main reason? Or are there other reasons?

```
BigInteger(string value)
{
  BigInteger result = new BigInteger(); // this one just returned in a Parse function

  // compute bigint

  // copy result to this
  data = new uint[maxLength];
  for (int i = 0; i < result.Length; i++)
    data[i] = result.data[i];

  Length = result.dataLength;  
}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There could be many reasons - research the *Factory method pattern*.

With your example - many consider it a bad practice to have significant logic in/called from a constructor (I don't want to throw an exception from a constructor unless it's a missing parameter).  Using a factory method allows for implementation guaranteed to run at object construction but not in the constructor.

Answer (score 2):

> there's no constructor taking a string

There's no *technical* reason why you couldn't.  The designers just chose not to duplicate code that already exists and *adds no pragmatic value* - it's still one line of code, it's *clearer* what you're trying to do, reduces the number of errors by passing in a wrong type, etc. etc.

It also makes it consistent with other numeric types that do not have a non-default constructor (you can't say `int i = new int(4)`);

The bottom line is - the *value* in such a constructor needs to outweigh the *cost* to implement, test, document, and ship the new feature.

Comment: But you *can* say `new int()`, so it *looks* like `int` has a constructor. (Though it's not really a constructor, it's just initializing a value type to its default value.)

Comment: @svick true - I've clarified that in my answer.

Answer (score 1):

See @Moho for answer, Factory method pattern.

I personally think `BigInteger.Parse` covers it better. You have some value in this case a string, and you want it to convert it to a BigNumber. A constructor with a string parameter doesn't not tell wat is going to happen. For all you know it is just doing a Console.WriteLine with the string instead of something different. `Parse` tells you something more...

Comment: I think the implied semantics of a constructor are pretty clear: somehow create a value of the given type based on the parameters given. That certainly does not include doing `WriteLine()` with the parameter. Though `Parse()` is clearer, because it explains what does the parameter actually mean.